# C# WebMethod is not returning JSON object

Tags: c#, jsonp, jquery-select2, webmethod

I have this WebMethod in C#:

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
[System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCors("*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public List<DatoMaestro> ObtieneEspecialidades()
{
    List<DatoMaestro> especialidades = new List<DatoMaestro>();

    especialidades.Add(new DatoMaestro(1, "Dermatología"));
    especialidades.Add(new DatoMaestro(2, "Medicina General"));

    return especialidades;
    //var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    //return oSerializer.Serialize(o);
}
```

When I call it, an xml is returned, even when I specified that Json must be returned. When I use the JavaScriptSerializer, the JSON is returned but inside a  to so that it is a valid XML document.

I am trying to populate a select2 control by calling that WebMethod.

This is the client code:

```
$('#Especialidad').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    width: '80%',
    placeholder: 'Seleccione la especialidad',
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:32617/Maestro.asmx/ObtieneEspecialidades",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        results: function(data, page) {
            alert(data);
            var mas = (page * 10) < data.total; // whether or not there are more results available

// notice we return the value of more so Select2 knows if more results can be loaded
            return {results: data.especialidades, more: mas};
        }
    }
});
```

When I call it, I received the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

which is obvious because  tag appears as the first element.

Comment: does the call works and returns something at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'POST' instead of 'GET' in Javascript-calling:

From [WebService returns XML even when ResponseFormat set to](http://forums.asp.net/p/1327142/2652827.aspx) :

Make sure that the request is a POST request, not a GET. [Scott Guthrie has a post explaining why.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx)

Also check this out: 
http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/http-post-and-get-in-xml-web-service-asmx/